# Computer won't shut down

Tags: shutdown

My computer will not shut down. I press the shutdown button in the drop box and then it looks like its shutting down and the screen goes black but the computer itself does not stop working and the light does not turn off.

Here are the specs:

- UBUNTU 10.04 (Lucid)
- Kernel: Linux 2.6.32-23-generic
- GNOME 2.30.2
- Memory: 495.7 MiB
- Processor: Intel(R) Pentium(R) 4 CPU 1.80GHz

Comment: first thought is that some process refuses to die or some volume refuses to unmount.  another possibility is that there is some race condition in your shutdown.  think - process A waits for process B to exit cleanly before dying.  what happens if process B was dead before process A starts listening?

Comment: another possibility (more likely) is power management setting in the bios...play with them a bit.  not enough info to be definitive.  that's why these are comments not answers

Answer (score 3):

From the command line try the following command

```
sudo shutdown -h now
```

See whether the system shut-down normally. if not take a note of the messages and write them here.

Comment: Or the shortform `sudo poweroff`

Answer (score 2):

The solution for me was open Synaptic and install `fglrx` and `xvba-va-driver` for my ATI graphics card. I did a manual `poweroff` once more; now it's all working correctly. I hope this will help.